# map is undefined if object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this in my jsx

```
{get(applicant, 'user.name').map((obj,i) => <span>{obj}</span>}
```

if user.name not exist, my app will crash, why get doesn't solve the problem here? It's lodash's get.

If I do applicant.user.name.map my app will have chance to crash.

Comment: If it's lodash then why don't you read the [documentation on `_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])`](https://lodash.com/docs#get)? _"Gets the value at path of object. **If the resolved value is `undefined`, the defaultValue is returned in its place**."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) return `undefined` if path doesn't exist. As result `undefined.map` throws the error. You should pass `[]` as the third argument, in that case, if path is not exist `_.get` returns `[]` and `[].map` does not throws the error:

```
{get(applicant, 'user.name', []).map((obj,i) => <span>{obj}</span>}
```

Comment: It's strange. When `.map` is executed on empty array, function which passed to `.map`, is not called ever. Look at this example - https://jsfiddle.net/levvsha/g9zcg18v/ Can you paste your full code and full error text?